# Typescript: "property getName is missing from type" when casting a type to a json object

Tags: typescript

I have this Class that I use to import data into from a json file:

```
import Players from './players.json';

class Player {
  name: string;
}

const PLAYERS: Player[] = Players;
```

This works perfectly fine. But as soon as I add a getter method like so:

```
class Player {
  name: string;

  getName(): string {
    return this.name;
  }
}
```

Then I get an error on the `const PLAYERS` line because `Property 'getName' is missing in type`. Which is understandable: The json objects doesn't have the getName property, so it becomes incompatible. The first workaround I can think of is to create a second Class to wrap around the first Class, use one class to import the json data and create the getter and other methods on the second class. But that's a really hacky solution. Is there a better more elegant solution to this problem I'm not aware about?

Comment: There is no such thing like a "JSON object". [JSON](http://json.org) is a text representation of some data structure.

Comment: what does `console.log(JSON.parse(Players));` show?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the typescript error go away by just doing:

```
const PLAYERS: Player[] = Players as any;
```

However, doing `PLAYERS[0].getName()` will fail, so that's probably not what you want.

The normal way of doing this is to assign to a new type. Your backend (or JSON file) returns Player[], and then you need to convert that into a new type. Could be as simple as:

```
class PlayerModel {
    name: string;
    getName(): string {
        return this.name;
    }

    constructor(data: Player) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
        // any other stuff you need to do here
    }
}
```

Then you'd do:

```
const PLAYERS: PlayerModel[] = Players.map(p => new PlayerModel(p));
```

and now `PLAYERS[0].getName()` should work fine.